# How to close cursor in MongoKit

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database-cursor, mongokit

I'm using MongoKit to perform iteration over a huge amount of data.

During this process my cursor becomes invalid, and I'm getting

`OperationFailure: cursor id '369397057360964334' not valid at server`

I've read in mailing lists that I can pass parameter `timeout=False` to `.find()` method, but [PyMongo FAQ](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.0/faq.html#what-does-operationfailure-cursor-id-not-valid-at-server-mean) says that I vave to take care of closing cursor myself.

But I didn't find methods in MongoKit for that.

Do I need to close cursor myself, and if yes - how can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll have to close the cursor since the MongoDB server won't time out the cursor for you, given that you specifically asked it not to.

simply call `del` on your cursor. The default pymongo implementation for `__del__` will notify the server to kill the cursor.

Assuming something like:

```
cursor = db.test.find(timeout=False)
```

Simply do this when you're done:

```
del cursor
```