# How to close cursors in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7

Hi I am fetching documents from mongdb using **mongo_collection.find()** , this collection has 600k documents. after traversing 400k documents I am geting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mongo_opp.py", line 324, in <module>
    obj.indexAnswer()
  File "mongo_opp.py", line 241, in indexAnswer
    for dict_result in result:
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1032, in next
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pymongo/cursor.py", line 974, in _refresh
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pymongo/cursor.py", line 864, in __send_message
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pymongo/helpers.py", line 112, in _unpack_response
pymongo.errors.CursorNotFound: Cursor not found, cursor id: 83302133311
```

The solutions to this problem is setting timeout paramter ***mongo_collection.find(timeout=False)*** which I found in below links,

[StackOveflowLink1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199729/pymongo-errors-cursornotfound-cursor-id-not-valid-at-server)

[StacKOverflowLink2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298354/mongodb-cursor-id-not-valid-error)

Setting timeout parameter makes cursor open for unlimited time, which will affect system performance. Can anybody help me with cursor close connection. Help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can solve this using **del** keyword

```
result = mongo_collection.find(no_cursor_timeout=True)

del result
```

Check [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392318/how-to-close-cursor-in-mongokit), [Link2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/CrPTP3Rye5I)

Answer (score 1):

To closing the cursor you need to remove the variable where you're put the query result

```
del cursor
```

or

```
cursor.close()
```

you can also fix the probleme by choosing a low value of batch_size:

(with Pymongo for example)

```
col.find({}).batch_size(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python uses reference counting for object lifetime management, when the Cursor object goes out of scope the garbage collector would call __die() which closes the cursor. If you want explicit control, you can call close() by yourself.

Close() call __die() internally.Check this [out](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/cursor.py#L276)